# "No such file or directory" error when I try to run a Linux script written from Windows system

Tags: linux, windows, bash, debian-based

I have written some script files in my PC with Windows7, then I upload these files to remote Linux computer. The system on remote computer is  :

```
Debian 3.14.15-2 (2014-08-09) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

by `uname -a`. With `ls` command I see the files are successfully uploaded to the expected directory:

```
xxx@ion:/mnt/backup/TIEGCM2/saturation_2.0$ ls
Apr_P_150_res5.0.job  Apr_P_200_res5.0.job Apr_P_100_res5.0.job
```

these files are C shell script:

```
xxx@ion:/mnt/backup/TIEGCM2/saturation_2.0$ file Apr_P_200_res5.0.job
Apr_P_200_res5.0.job: C shell script, ASCII text executable, with CRLF line terminators
```

However, when I run one of them with nohup, it throw error "No such file or directory":

```
xxx@ion:/mnt/backup/TIEGCM2/saturation_2.0$ nohup ./Apr_P_200_res5.0.job &
[3] 17065
xxx@ion:/mnt/backup/TIEGCM2/saturation_2.0$ nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'
nohup: failed to run command './Apr_P_200_res5.0.job': No such file or directory

[3]+  Exit 127                nohup ./Apr_P_200_res5.0.job
```

The file exists of course which could be proven by `ls`. The more strange thing is, when I written scripts directly in Linux systems by `vi`, then it will run without any problem. When I created a script file in Linux, download to my Windows7 PC, modified content but keep filename untouched, and then uploaded to Linux; the script file will run without any problem. However, if I created a script file in Linux, download to my Windows7 PC, modified content and the filename, and then uploaded to Linux; the script file will refuse to run and throw "No such file or directory" error.

So what's wrong?

Comment: Please show your scripts and the output of `ls -Al`.

Comment: Also, clarify whether `nohup` has anything to do with this. That said, CRLF lineendings are sometimes an issue on POSIX systems. Another question that comes up is what the actual interpreter of those files is: Is it C-shell as per your question, BASH as per your tags or something different as per your script's shebang line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below line in your output indicates you're having dos line-endings "CR - Carriage returns" in your file.

> with CRLF line terminators

Try running `cat -v your_file` , if it shows ^M at the end of each line you'd need to run `dos2unix` on them, eg `dos2unix your_file` to convert them to unix format